# Plot labels position changed in GraphicsGrid[]

Tags: plotting, visualization

I plan to align several array plots with labels at the top of each property. However, when I use GraphicsGrid[] function, the label becomes repositioned, and the labels are away from the plot, which makes it confusing. Is there any way to circumvent this behavior?

Example:

```
a = Table[
  ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 5}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Test"], {3}, {3}]
```

returns plots with appropriate labels, but

```
GraphicsGrid[a]
```

returns plots in which plot labels are shifted upward, and relationship between the labels and plots are less clear.

Thank you very much in advance.

Takashi.

Answer (score 4):

- `Grid` work for this cases.

```
Grid[a]
```

[image]

- or `Alignment -> Top`.

```
GraphicsGrid[a, Alignment -> Top]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!!